# DEVEXPRESS how to cash usercontrol in NavigationFrame

Tags: wpf, devexpress

I'm using DEVEXPRESS NavigationFrame to Navigate group of user control my problem is the first time the usercontrol load take few second after that work fine
so i need to know how  cach all usercontrol in NavigationFrame 
or how to Render or load wpf window without show it then i can Navigate all usercontrol then show the window to avoid loading time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NavigationFrame.Source = UsercontrolName